# Problem about $\mathbb{P}^3(K)$

Tags: projective-geometry, quadratic-forms, projective-space, quadrics

Show that four skew lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ have two transversals in common.

I know that exist a quadric which contains three of the four lines....but i'm stuck

EDIT:

If the skew lines are $a,b,c,d$. Let $Q$ the quadric such that $a,b,c \subset Q$.
Then $d \cap Q=\text{{two point}}$? Why?

Comment: Possibly related to [Show that three pairwise non-intersecting lines in $ℝℙ^3$ have a transversal.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/781243/35416)

Comment: I have already showed it